# Histogram of lexicographically ordered list in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, statistics, histogram

I have a list of tuples, containing floats, e.g.:

```
myList = [(1.0,2.0), (1.0,0.5), (2.0,1.0), (3.0,2.0), (3.0,0.0)]
```

The lexicographic order of the tuples is:

```
mySortedList = [(1.0,0.5), (1.0,2.0), (2.0,1.0), (3.0,0.0), (3.0,2.0)]
```

I.e. one tuple is smaller than the other, if both entries of the tuple are smaller.
Now I want to make a histogram, that shows the distribution of data that is ordered lexicographically like mySortedList. Is there any way do so with a built-in function in python? plt.hist works only for onedimensional lists. Btw is a histogram a good approach at all, to show the density in this case? (My statistic skills are rather limited, sorry)

Comment: "Now I want to make a histogram, that shows the distribution of data that is ordered lexicographically like mySortedList" can you elaborate on this?

Comment: In this case: `print(sorted(myList,key=sum))` would work

Comment: Does my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
print(sorted(myList,key=sum))
```

Would work

Output:

```
[(1.0,0.5), (1.0,2.0), (2.0,1.0), (3.0,0.0), (3.0,2.0)]
```